# Replace black diamond with a question mark in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, unicode

I need to replace a black diamond with a question mark in a windows service. I tried adding uFFFD, xFFFD, EF BF BD, ï ¿ ½ formats to detect this unknown symbol but it did not work. Is it possible to add this special unknown character to regex in c#?

What is the correct unicode format to replace this unknown symbol?

the regex i am using in the code is as below I need to add this unknown special character to the set below.

```
public static string regExpValidation = @"^[-0-9a-zA-Z\&\+\{\}\.\>''-'/\sŸÚ]";
```

Below are the different alternatives i tried

```
public static string regExpValidation = @"^[-0-9a-zA-Z\&\+\U+FFFD\{\}\.\>''-'/\sŸÚ]";

public static string regExpValidation = @"^[-0-9a-zA-Z\&\+\uFFFD\{\}\.\>''-'/\sŸÚ]";
public static string regExpValidation = @"^[-0-9a-zA-Z\&\+\EF BF BD\{\}\.\>''-'/\sŸÚ]";
public static string regExpValidation = @"^[-0-9a-zA-Z\&\+\ï ¿ ½\{\}\.\>''-'/\sŸÚ]";
```

But the regex did not recognize that unknown character. how to add this character to regex?

Comment: what do you mean by skip??

Comment: There's a lot of context missing here. Where has the value come from, and what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @AmitJoki along with other special charecters on regex expression- if this unknown character comes.. program should not throw an error. The characters mentioned in code there are allowed. i should join this special character to that

Comment: @JonSkeet I do not have control over where it came from. But i need to add this unknown special character to my regex code. So that if this character comes in text file. an exception will not be thrown.

Comment: You still haven't provided enough information about what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to remove all occurrences from the string? Something else?

Comment: @JonSkeet  what ever is there on that regex code- only those characters are allowed in the input text file to process. if any different character(which is not there in regex code given) sneaks in a line some where-program will throw an exception. Since this unknown special character came in text file an exception was thrown. Now i need to add this character "black diamond with question mark" to regex code so that exception will not be thrown.

Comment: Well what's throwing the exception? And have you even diagnosed which character you're looking at? (My guess is that it's U+FFFD, but you should confirm that - along with showing *exactly* what you tried that didn't work, and what you mean by "didn't work".) Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. The link you shared is very useful.I will try it. I had updated different ways i tried in the question. It "didn't work" means the regex could not recognize the unknown character.

Comment: Well we have no idea what you're *doing* with that regex, which really doesn't help. What is the `{246}` meant to achieve? A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to replace that unknown symbol black diamond with a question mark.

Finally with the below code i was able to detect that symbol and replace it.

```
convertedString = Regex.Replace(inputString,@"\xEF\xBF\xBD"," ");
```

Hope this will be helpful for someone if they are trying to replace this unknown symbol ï ¿ ½ or Black diamond with question mark

Answer (score -2):

i think its possible once i needed something like that i don't remember what it was lol so i just googled for its ASCII code on google so here it is 
♥
and i tried once the number pad in the keyboard. hehehe i don't remember where i tried that (on notepad or somewhere) but i got some interesting symbols 
i hope this helped you